# Is space in a rotating frame flat?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, curvature

Apparently in papers like "Space geometry of rotating platforms: an operational approach" https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0207104 (page 21) and https://www.amherst.edu/.../view/10267/original/reden05.pdf (page 10) they calculate the Riemann tensor and the curvature scalar, finding them nonzero, and conclude that the metric in a rotating frame is curved.

How do we reconcile this conclusion with the fact that the Riemann is a tensor and if it is zero in the inertial frame than remains zero after coordinate transofrmation?

The situation is even worse for the curvature scalar! 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're talking about the spatial geometry, not the 3+1 dimensional geometry.